# Pandas fill missing time series data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series dataframe that has data like the following:

| Week_Ending | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 8/5/2021 | 1000 |
| 8/12/2021 | 1122 |
| 8/19/2021 | 980 |
| nan | 1000 |
| nan | 1234 |

The week ending dates are sometimes missing and I want to have the missing ones be equal to the previous date + 7 days. So the nan values should be '08/26/2021' and '09/02/2021' respectively. How can I do this? I've tried playing around with interpolate but nothing has been changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert if necessary:
df["Week_Ending"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Week_Ending"])

mn = df["Week_Ending"].min()
df["Week_Ending"] = [mn + pd.Timedelta(days=7 * i) for i in df.index]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Week_Ending  Sales
0  2021-08-05   1000
1  2021-08-12   1122
2  2021-08-19    980
3  2021-08-26   1000
4  2021-09-02   1234
```

---

EDIT:

```py
mask = df["Week_Ending"].isna()
df.loc[mask, "tmp"] = df.groupby((mask != mask.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
df["Week_Ending"] = df["Week_Ending"].ffill()
df.loc[mask, "Week_Ending"] = df[mask].apply(
    lambda x: x["Week_Ending"] + pd.Timedelta(days=7 * x["tmp"]), axis=1
)
df = df.drop(columns="tmp")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Week_Ending  Sales
0  2021-08-05   1000
1  2021-08-12   1122
2  2021-08-19    980
3  2021-08-26   1000
4  2021-09-02   1234
5  2021-09-19    980
6  2021-09-26   1234
```

`df` used:

```
  Week_Ending  Sales
0  2021-08-05   1000
1  2021-08-12   1122
2  2021-08-19    980
3         NaT   1000
4         NaT   1234
5  2021-09-19    980
6         NaT   1234
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Andrej! I think that you are close but not exactly what I was looking for. When I ran your code it was filling in the nans by adding a 7 to the smallest date and then adding a 7 to the next nan. What this led to is say the smallest date was 2016/01/01 and then we had a year and a half of non-missing values the next missing value is getting filled as 2016/01/07 instead of say 2017/07/01 or something like that. Then if there were more non-missing values followed by a nan that nan also got filled with say 2016/01/14

Comment: I just need it to add a 7 to the date value in the previous row instead of the previous nan

Comment: Instead of the minimum used in your code it should say previous row but I'm not sure how to do that. Also I wasn't the one that downvoted I actually appreciate any help that I can get!

Comment: Hi Andrej, haven't tried your edited version yet but came back to say that actually your original version worked like a charm! I just had to reset the index on my part. Thank you very much!